# Ionic: Can't scroll up while using anchorScroll in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

We are using scrollTo functionality in ionic application by setting the `$location.hash(id)` and `$anchorScroll()`. The scroll to bottom is working fine, but we can't scroll up the page once the page scrolled to some location using `$anchorScroll` and `$location.hash()`.

See the issue clearly in [codepen](http://codepen.io/eanas/pen/azGByM/). Click on *To Bottom* button and try to scroll up back.

Please provide a solution to fix this scroll issue.

Answer (score 6):

On "ion-content" div add overflow-scroll="true"

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
```

then in your controller:

```
$scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
    $location.hash(id);
    $ionicScrollDelegate.anchorScroll();
};
```

Further information for this issue in Ionic Framework can be found here:
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/content-stuck-after-anchorscroll/776

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me on a browser and Android, but is not working on iOS

Comment: @jcarballo follow my answer step in ios platform it will work for iOS  as well .

Comment: You saved me as well! this answer should be picked as correct one!